# Trying to debug a custom .sort in a JS array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[A link to the Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/dD2fF0jGq1rKe1sTeBAg?p=info)
I've been working on a button and list system in jQuery for awhile now.  Recently I decided to make my code more reproducible.  I want to make it so I just have to add classes or IDs, and I don't have to add any additional code.  I'm very close to doing that for my entire site.  So if you go to [this site](http://www.royoswalt44.com/base-inserts-parallels.html) specifically you will see it in action.

If you click on any buttons, in any order, it will arrange chronologically.
The bugs come from closing them.
If you click at least three, close the middle one, then click a new button, the sort function falls apart and that closed middle one is now floating with the wrong class.
Below is my current jQuery.  On my site, ignore the "All Years" button.  I'll work on that after I figure out this bug.

```
    //the variables needed for the floating buttons
    var groupArray = $(".yearGroup");
    var buttonArray = $(".buttonGroup");
    var hideGroupArray = $(".hideGroup");
    var closeBarArray = $(".closeBar");
    var closeBar = $("#allCloseBar");
    var allButtonArray = [];


sortElements = function(a,b)
{
    if (a.text() < b.text())
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (a.text() > b.text())
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}   
$.each(buttonArray, function(i, item) {
    $(this).click(function(){

        console.log($(buttonArray[i]).text())
        console.log($(closeBarArray[i]).text())
        //for removing the tooltip when the button is clicked.  Mostly for Firefox bug
        $(".ui-tooltip-content").parents('div').remove();
        $(hideGroupArray[i-1]).slideToggle(slideToggleDuration, function(){
            htmlBody.animate({scrollTop: $(groupArray[i-1]).offset().top - 25}, {duration: timeDuration, easing: 'easeOutBack'});
            $(buttonArray[i]).toggleClass("float", 1200);
            if ($(groupArray[i-1]).height() > 0)
            {
                //This will stop any animations if the user scrolls.
                htmlBody.bind("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", function(e)
                {
                if ( e.which > 0 || e.type === "mousedown" || e.type === "mousewheel"){
                htmlBody.stop().unbind('scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup');
                }
                });
                closeBar.addClass("floatCloseBar");
                $(closeBarArray[i]).hide();
                allButtonArray.splice(0, 0, $(buttonArray[i]));             
                var timer;
                var delay = 1500;
                $(buttonArray[i]).hover(function() {
                //This will stop any animations if the user scrolls.
                htmlBody.bind("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", function(e)
                {
                if ( e.which > 0 || e.type === "mousedown" || e.type === "mousewheel"){
                 htmlBody.stop().unbind('scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup'); 
                }
                });
                var link = $(groupArray[i-1]);
                var offset = link.offset();
                var top2 = offset.top;
                var left = offset.left;
                var bottom = top2 + $(groupArray[i-1]).outerHeight();
                //bottom = Math.abs(bottom - offset.top);
                var right = $(window).width() - link.width();
                right = Math.abs(offset.left - right);
                var scrollDuration = 0;
                if (inRange($(buttonArray[i]).offset().top, $(groupArray[i-1]).position().top, bottom))
                {
                    //console.log("fast");
                scrollDuration = 500;
                //$(group).addClass("hoverYear");
                }

                else if ($(buttonArray[i]).offset().top <= $(groupArray[i-1]).offset().top && allButtonArray.length == 1)
                {
                    //console.log("fast");
                    scrollDuration = 500;
                    //$(group).removeClass("hoverYear");
                }
                else if ($(buttonArray[i]).offset().top > 495 && $(buttonArray[i]).offset().top < 1700 && !inRange($(buttonArray[i]).offset().top, $(groupArray[i-1]).position().top, bottom))
                {
                    scrollDuration = 1000;
                    //console.log("slow");
                    //$(group).removeClass("hoverYear");
                }
                else if ($(buttonArray[i]).offset().top > 1701 && $(buttonArray[i]).offset().top < 3000 && !inRange($(buttonArray[i]).offset().top, $(groupArray[i-1]).position().top, bottom))
                {
                    scrollDuration = 1500;
                    //console.log("slower");
                    //$(group).removeClass("hoverYear");
                }
                else if ($(buttonArray[i]).offset().top > 3001 && $(buttonArray[i]).offset().top < 6000 && !inRange($(buttonArray[i]).offset().top, $(groupArray[i-1]).position().top, bottom))
                {
                    scrollDuration = 2000;
                    //console.log("much slower");
                    //$(group).removeClass("hoverYear");
                }
                else if ($(buttonArray[i]).offset().top > 6001 && !inRange($(buttonArray[i]).offset().top, $(groupArray[i-1]).position().top, bottom))
                {
                    scrollDuration = 2500;
                    console.log("the slowest");
                    //$(group).removeClass("hoverYear");
                }
                else
                {
                    scrollDuration = 500;
                }
                //to prevent the various hover states to take control when the button isn't floating
                if (!($(buttonArray[i])).hasClass("float"))
                {
                    scrollDuration = 0;
                    console.log("doesnt have class")
                }
                // on mouse in, start a timeout
                timer = setTimeout(function() {

                //the delay for the hover scroll feature
                htmlBody.animate({scrollTop: $(groupArray[i-1]).offset().top}, scrollDuration, 'easeInOutCubic');
                }, delay);
                }, function() {
                // on mouse out, cancel the timer
                clearTimeout(timer);
                });

                $.each(allButtonArray, function(j, val){
                $(allButtonArray[j]).appendTo(closeBar);
                console.log(allButtonArray.length);
                arrowDown.show();
                arrowUp.show();
                arrowDown.prependTo(closeBar);
                arrowUp.appendTo(closeBar);

                //Changes the width of the buttons based upon how many are on the screen
                if (allButtonArray.length > 7)
                {
                    $("float").css('width', '7%');
                    $(val).css('width', '7%');
                    $(allButtonArray[0]).css('width','7%');
                    allButtonArray.sort(sortElements);
                    //console.log(val);
                }
                else if (allButtonArray.length <= 7)
                {
                    $(val).css("width", '10%');
                    $("float").css("width", '10%');
                    allButtonArray.sort(sortElements);
                    //console.log(val);
                }
                });
            }
            if ($(groupArray[i-1]).height() == 0)
            {               
                $(buttonArray[i]).css("width", '50%');                  
                allButtonArray.splice(allButtonArray.indexOf($(buttonArray[i])), 1);
                console.log(allButtonArray.length);
                $(closeBarArray[i]).show();
                $(buttonArray[i]).appendTo($(closeBarArray[i]));
                arrowDown.show();
                arrowUp.show();
                arrowDown.prependTo(closeBar);
                arrowUp.appendTo(closeBar);
            }
            if (group2001.height() == 0 && group2002.height() == 0 && group2003.height() == 0 && group2004.height() == 0 && group2005.height() == 0 && group2006.height() == 0 && group2007.height() == 0 
                && group2008.height() == 0 && group2009.height() == 0 && group2010.height() == 0 && group2011.height() == 0 && group2012.height() == 0)
            {
                $(closeBarArray[i]).removeClass("floatCloseBar");
                htmlBody.animate({scrollTop: revealAllButton.offset().top - 75}, 500);
                arrowDown.hide();
                arrowUp.hide();
            //console.log($(document).height() + " the current height");
            }
        });
        $(buttonArray[i]).toggleClass("openClose");
        $(buttonArray[i]).toggleClass("openClose2");
    });
});

function inRange(x, min, max){
   return (x >= min && x <= max);   
}
```

If you would like a reference to what worked previously, I could post that code.  It is much more bulky and much less organized.  I've tried many different things to eliminate the bug but I'm at a loss.  My knowledge of JS scope is limited. 
And thanks for any help, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Try eliminating all the code that isn't directly involved in the sorting, replacing inputs with hardcoded values, etc.

Comment: I have one locally.  What would be the best way to post that?

Comment: you can either edit your question to supply it, use a service that allows you to write, test and share code easily (JsFiddle, JsBin, Plunker, etc) and give us a link or both.

Comment: Apparently I need more than 10 reputation for 2 links.  Here's a link to the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/dD2fF0jGq1rKe1sTeBAg?p=info.

Comment: Well I'm getting very close to discovering this.  At this line: $(buttonArray[i]).toggleClass("float", 1200); I removed the delay.  The float class wasn't being added to the first array item.  However, I'm still having issues with certain closed buttons.